# Does advantage on Strength checks grant advantage on grappling?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple, advantage-and-disadvantage

I’m playing a grappling Eldritch Knight, and wanted to know if advantage on Strength checks (from the [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) spell) would make my grapple check - which is an Athletics check - have advantage.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game and edition you're asking about?

Comment: Does 5e mean "Dungeons and Dragons 5e" of the fifth edition of another game?

Comment: My bad I’m playing dnd 5e

Comment: Thanks, Ben, adding that tag should get the question reopened.  Please take a look [at this question on grappling](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97982/22566), it appears to be related.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I saw that and I was still unclear if adv on strength also counts for athletics.

Comment: Hi Ben, just wanted to say welcome!

Comment: Are you asking specifically about checks made to initiate grapple attempts, or checks made to resist grapple attempts as well?

Answer (score 29):

### Advantage on Strength checks gives advantage on grapples

The rule for [grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) says:

> ...you try to seize the target by making a grapple check instead of an attack roll: a **Strength** (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check...

Emphasis mine.

*[Enlarge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce)* gives advantage to all Strength checks, which include Strength (Athletics) checks.

Comment: As a bonus, this text also means that you have advantage to contest anything smaller that tries to grapple you! Unless you decide to use your Dexterity (Acrobatics) check instead...

Answer (score 8):

A Strength (Athletics) check is, in fact, a Strength check - the hint is in the word "Strength".

If you are initiating a [grapple](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Combat#toc_42) then a Strength (Athletics) check is what you use and if you have advantage(disadvantage) on Strength checks you have advantage(disadvantage) on this check because, as pointed out above, its a Strength check.

If you are trying to avoid or escape from a grapple then you can choose to use Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics). The first is a Strength check, the second isn't - its a Dexterity check. As a quick aside, Initiative is a Dexterity check so advantage(disadvantage) on Dexterity checks gives you the same on Initiative rolls.

If you are keen on building a grappler, you should check out the [Grappler's Guide](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?468737-The-Grappler-s-Manual-(2-0)-Grappling-in-5th-Edition), one of the prime things it recommends aiming for is access to the *Enlarge* spell, partly to get the advantage you identified but also to allow you to grapple Huge sized creatures.

Answer (score 2):

### I believe so

When you initiate a [grapple](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Grappling), you do so by:

> ... making a grapple check instead of an attack roll: a **Strength (Athletics) check** contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics)

Meaning that advantage on Strength checks does give you advantage when trying to grapple.